# Why do current transformers saturate with high short circuit currents?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, electricity

When there is a severe short circuit current due to the faults in transmission lines ,sometimes current transformers get saturated.Voltage of the faulty line drops sharply but ct still saturates.As far as I know it is the voltage that saturates the core not overcurrent.Am i missing something?

Comment: Current is what produces flux, not voltage.

Comment: The line voltage has very little to do with anything in a CT. Your knowledge was at fault.

Comment: A current transformer measures current, not voltage. You'll get the same reading from a current transformer with 1V@1Amp as you will with 12V@1Amp.  Actually, there isn't really a voltage across the section of wire that is going through the transformer, so it really is **just the current** that matters.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

*Figure 1. A current transformer and ammeter. Source: [Wikipedia](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_transformer).*

As can be seen from the illustration the current transformer has no idea what the voltage of the circuit being measured is. It simply couples the current from the primary (the large conductor) to the secondary and the current is reduced by the turns ratio.

> Voltage of the faulty line drops sharply but CT still saturates.

Yes. A given core can only handle so much flux. As you reach that limit the core will saturate.

> As far as I know it is the voltage that saturates the core not overcurrent. Am i missing something?

Yes. The operating voltage of a **current** transformer is irrelevant. It only transforms current.

Comment: There is still a burden voltage produced on the sensed line, right? It's just comparatively small.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal Operation the CT in in MMF balance .This means that the Ampere turns are equal and opposite .So if N is say 50 then current is divided by 50 .This would mean that 1 amp would flow in the secondary when 50 amps flow in the primary .The real CT has finite resistance in the secondary circuit .The secondary resistance could be say half an ohm because the wire has a DCR of 300milliohm and the burden resister is 0.47 ohm .At 50 amps AC the secondary current will be very close to 1 amp because the core has very low losses and looks like a high value parallel resister of say 100 ohm .If we now put a fault current of say 1000 amp into our CT the output volts would be 20 times what it was at 50 Amps if the core could support the Volt microsecond product .If the real core wont it will saturate and under report the current .Large core area and low burden resistance improve the CT linearity at high currents.